# How to generate Point Cloud using MATLAB from raw ADC data of IWR6843 Radar?

Tags: matlab

I have raw ADC binary data of an IWR6843 Radar. I have configuration files. I have mmWave SDK, mmStudio and MATLAB installed. Now I need to generate point cloud from the binary ADC output using the parameters. I need a general guideline of how I can start with my current files and environment setup. Any video tutorial or any document that might show me how I can start will be a great help.

I have tried to load the binary file into mmStudio and failed. Same for MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this git repository: https://github.com/HavocFiXer/mmMesh/blob/master/README.md

In the repository, there is a pc_generation.py file which takes .bin file as input and generate point cloud data. You must change the parameters in configuration.py file as per IWR6843 sensor.

I also have IWR6843ISK-ODS with DCA1000EVM to capture raw .bin file and generate point cloud from it. I am having some troubles in getting raw data using DCA1000EVM.
Let me know if the script works for your .bin file. It will be helpful for me as well as IWR6843 and IWR6843ISK-ODS are pretty much similar.

Regards,

Pushkar

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).